# Communications link failure Error sometimes happens in AppEngine when connecting to google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I published a backend project in google App Engine since 1 year, and all seems good, 1 week ago this Exception started to throw in logs sometimes (not always) during executing a JPA select query in Cloud SQL and sometimes the query is just returning the result successfully:

> Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 309,979 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 309,981 milliseconds ago.
>   Error Code: 0
>   Call: SELECT ID, created_time, CURRENCY, IP, NAME FROM country_table
>   Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Country.findAll" referenceClass=Country sql="SELECT ID, created_time, CURRENCY, IP, NAME FROM country_table")

and sometimes this exception is stopping some queries to be executed:

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 219,443 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 219,446 milliseconds ago.
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:44)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3851)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2471)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2739)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2149)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2313)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1007)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:250)

Comment: I've applied almost most of the solutions like adding parameters to the JPA connection string like autoReconnect, interactiveClient, maxReconnects, failOverReadOnly, and however the error still happening, and with every single request coming to me Im getting a new entity manager and close it right after

Answer (score 0):

This is because MySQL closed the connection.

Probably JPA will automatically reconnect to the database. If the transaction result is correct, you can ignore this message.

Or you can extend the timer until connection close with `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` on developer console. This can reduce the message.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right, the transaction result is correct!, but why out of sudden this error started throwing ?, can you tell me how i can do that from the developer console ?

Comment: Select your instance on developer console, then EDIT -> Add database flags -> Add item. Select `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout`, and set values. The default value is 28800 (8hours). You can extend timer by setting the value larger than this. Then press `save`.

Comment: thanks a lot :), but I still need to understand what cause this message to start printing recently, all timeout values are default and never touched

Comment: the thing that I don't understand, the time out is 8 hours, if i sent a request now to the serve this message will be printed, if I sent it again after 1 min it still getting printed.

Comment: II increased both flags to the maximum, and Im still having the problem, and now start stopping some queries to be executed

Comment: @TamerSaleh How did you fix this problem?

Comment: @AngryLeo its not permanently fixed yet and still happening in some rare cases, but my wild guess is it means something wrong with the DB server memory or something its more than than just a waiting time issue